Setting bounds on distribution integrals
Say if I have 3 independent probability distributions, $P_X(x), 0 \leq x \leq 2$, $Q_Y(y), -1 \leq y \leq 0$, $R_Z(z), 0 \leq z \leq 1$, and I want to find the probability that $X + Y > \sqrt{2} Z$. The integral is clearly $\int \int \int P_X(x) Q_Y(y) R_Z(z) dx dy dz$, but how would one set up the bounds for the integrals themselves?
If you had $\int^{0}_{-1} dy$ and $\int^1_0 dz$, to meet the condition the final integral should be $\int^2_{\sqrt{2}z - y} dx$. However, this doesn't make sense, because in the situation where $z = 1$ and $y = -1$, your $x$ integral bounds don't work. Similarly, if you accounted for this, e.g. you only integrated $\int^{\sqrt{2}-2}_{-1} dy$, you aren't integrating over the full distribution of $Q_Y$.
How exactly do you correct for this problem? Is there a way to completely avoid it, e.g. trying to combine the distributions by summing them? Thanks in advance.

Let $-1 \le y \le 0, 0 \le z \le 1$,
then we have $0 \le -y \le 1$ and $0 \le \sqrt2 z \le \sqrt2$, thus we have
$0 \le \sqrt{2}z-y \le 1+\sqrt{2}$, to make sure that it doesn't exceed $2$, we just have to set the lower bound to be $\min(2, \sqrt2 z - y)$.
